# variable is read-only when it shouldn't be

Tags: gradle

When i execute this in my script

```
artifacts = ['abc123-com', 'abc123-ejb', 'abc123-spec', 'abc123-war', 'abc123-war2']

task clone_workspace() << {
    for (item in artifacts) {
        println item
    }
}
```

i get

```
> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'artifacts' on root project 'abc123'.
```

I have tried scoping to project with project.artifacts, and to ext with project.ext.artifacts.

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The following minimalist Gradle file illustrates that `project` already has a property for `artifacts` (documented [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html)):

```
println "TRACER : " + project.artifacts.class
```

output:

```
bash$ gradle
TRACER : class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultArtifactHandler_Decorated
```

By contrast, this version of the original is happier:

```
def myArtifacts = ['abc123-com', 'abc123-ejb', 'abc123-spec', 'abc123-war', 'abc123-war2']

task clone_workspace() << {
    for (item in myArtifacts) {
        println item
    }
}
```